Why can't I see HTTP tickets?
I'm currently exploring the fundamentals of Active Directory. I've set up a virtual environment with three computers:

DC at 172.16.0.1
Comp1 at 172.16.0.101
IIS at 172.16.0.100

My goal is to configure an IIS server and understand how Ticket Granting Tickets (TGTs) are formed. After encountering various challenges, I find myself in a situation where I'm attempting to access s-iis.rdomain.com from Comp1, which resolves to 172.16.0.100 (with the DC serving as the DNS server).
Upon accessing the web interface, I'm prompted for credentials. After entering them, I gain access to the website. Wireshark reveals a Kerberos request:

I have configured the IIS server to run under a service account named 'iis' and have also set up a corresponding SPN.

However, when I check with klist in the terminal, I don't see an HTTP TGS (Ticket Granting Service ticket). My question is, why is this the case? If I were to manually craft a TGS for the HTTP server (by the way, how can I do this?), would it allow me to access the website without prompting for credentials?

For the IIS server on a domain joined to the same domain, look into configuring your IIS site to use 'integrated authentication' then look at what on the client browser you need to set to use integrated authentication too. Might need to add the site to trusted sites but start with some of those and see where you get. Might need special configs in the web.config file of the IIS site.

Thank you for the comment. I have already enabled this option, and all other options are disabled. @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle

so Integrated authentication requires a browser that supports it, a web app configured to use it,  and potentially implicit identity impersonation (though that may be old info; .net 4x changed a lot about impersonation).

From my basic understanding of IIS, if you say you've set up the service to use the iis account, then you've set up the SPN on the wrong account. You've assigned it to the computer account instead. When IIS tries to use its service account to decrypt and verify the ticket, it's unable to do so because the ticket has been encrypted with the wrong key, so it falls back to Basic auth.

The AS issues a TGT (ticket-granting ticket), whereas the TGS issues a ST (service ticket). I don't think I've seen it called a "ticket granting service ticket" – that's a very ambiguous description since it can equally be interpreted as referring to both kinds of tickets.
I'm not sure why the service ticket is missing from cache in klist, but that definitely seems to happen a lot with Windows; it doesn't seem to prevent Kerberos from working otherwise.
